# How can I detect when a view controller has been dismissed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, segue

How can I detect back in my mapview (master) controller that the detail view controller has been dismissed?  I have a mapview with pins and annotations.  When the rightCalloutAccessoryView has been tapped on any annotation, a modal detail view controller is called via performSegueWithIdentifier. Incidentally, I don't know if this is correct or not, but the master and detail view controllers are attached by a navigation controller.

My goal is to take conditional action back on the mapview (master view) based on the user action on the detail view controller.  Specifically if they have tapped the Remove Pin feature, I want to remove the pin when control returns to the mapview.  If they simply tap the Done button, then I want the pin and annotation to remain on the screen.

With my limited knowledge, I'm able to remove the pin with the second line below but the problem is that I can see that the pin and annotation is removed right after the rightCalloutAccessorView icon is tapped and before the detail view is displayed.  So what that means is that if the user then taps the Done button on the detail screen, they would then return to the mapview with the pin and annotation removed already.  I only want it removed if the user taps the Remove button.

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PinDetail" sender:self];
   [self.mapView removeAnnotation:MA];
```

So my question really are:

1. Where do I put in the removeAnnotation code? In it's current place, the removal of the pin takes place even before the detail view appears.
2. How can I detect if the Remove button on the detail view has been tapped?

Thanks.

Comment: See my below post.When user clicks on Remove button call if ([m_Target respondsToSelector:m_Selector]) {[m_Target performSelector:m_Selector withObject:nil];} which is nothing but your removeAnnotation method and dismiss the detail view.And if user press done button then simply dismiss detail view without calling removeAnnotation.Got?

Comment: Thanks Nuzhat Zari. I'll go through this more in-depth in the morning.  I'm pretty happy with my progress so far but my knowledge of obj-c is spotty.  The whole delegate concept is something that I haven't gotten a good handle on yet, despite the fact that my code has some delegate code in it already that I've copied from various sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delegate to perform action on mapview based on action in detail view.In performSegueWithIndentifier you can assign your detail view as delegate of mapview and it will perform action for you.

Or you can set target and selector for detail view and when any action happens in detail view you can call that selector whose target is map view, as follows:
1.In performSegue method set target as follows:

```
 [theController setTarget:self andSelector:@selector(performAction)];
```

where theController is your destination view controller ie detail view controller.

2.In detail view controller .h file

```
 id m_Target;
  SEL m_Selector;
```

In detail view controller.m file:

```
- (void)setTarget:(id)inTarget andSelector:(SEL)inSelector
{
    m_Target = inTarget;
    m_Selector = inSelector;
}
```

3.Before dismissing detail view call

```
 if ([m_Target respondsToSelector:m_Selector]) {
            [m_Target performSelector:m_Selector withObject:nil];
        }
```

4.Define performAction in map view controller .m file

Comment: Thanks @Nuzhat Zari.  I was finally able to figure it out.  I also used two other resources that was very helpful:      http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2  and   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5l0QOyxZvI